# Quartz job isn't called

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, quartz

Im using Quartz 2.3.0 with spring boot and postresql :

My quartz jobs aren't called from database, after investigation, I noticed that "sched_name" in qrtz_simple_triggers table (QuartzScheduler ) is different than the script called in my log  (scheduler)

Any suggestions please?

qrtz_simple_triggers Table :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvc62.png

script called from spring boot log :

```
2021-04-07 15:11:18.713 DEBUG 13460 --- [SchedulerThread] jdbc.sqlonly                             :  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor298.invoke(null:-1)
201. SELECT TRIGGER_NAME, TRIGGER_GROUP, NEXT_FIRE_TIME, PRIORITY FROM QRTZ_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'scheduler' AND TRIGGER_STATE = 'WAITING' AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME <= 1617804708711 AND (MISFIRE_INSTR = -1 OR (MISFIRE_INSTR != -1 AND NEXT_FIRE_TIME >= 1617804618712)) ORDER BY NEXT_FIRE_TIME ASC, PRIORITY DESC
```

Quartz properties :

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================
 
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true
 
#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================
 
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
 
#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX 
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 25000

#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/AIRBUS_TMS
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = postgres
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = 12345
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery = select 1
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.provider = hikaricp
```

Comment: spring.quartz.scheduler-name=scheduler   . will this help?

Comment: I have an exeption :  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Active Scheduler of name 'scheduler' already registered in Quartz SchedulerRepository.`